# Reordering columns in a cursor passed as a ref cursor to a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is what I need to do...  I have a simple stored procedure that is defined like this...

```
TYPE p_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

CREATE PROCEDURE getAll_TableA(p_items OUT p_CURSOR) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_items FOR SELECT * FROM TableA;
END;
```

Now I have another stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reorderCursorColumns_TableA(i_items IN p_CURSOR, p_items OUT p_CURSOR) AS
BEGIN
   /*
   DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS
   */
   OPEN p_items FOR SELECT col5, col3, col2, col4, col1 FROM i_items;
END;
```

Is this possible?

Essentially, given a cursor, can I select from it to reorder the columns?

Comment: Do you know all the columns in the tableA ,before calling the procedure getAll_TableA

Comment: How do you want to use this changed order?

Comment: By the way, people generally use the `p_` prefix for parameter names, so naming a type `p_cursor` might cause confusion. And in any case, there is already a predefined cursor type named `sys_refcursor` so it would be better just to use that instead.

Comment: yes. i know the column order before hand

Comment: The changed order satisfies an ORM layer using OCCI that uses ordinals get fields from the returned cursor

Answer (score 1):

You can’t cast a cursor as a table. You would need to write a table function and then query that with something like:

```
select x, y, z
from   table(yourfunction(i_items));
```

The function would return a table (collection). You would need to define a collection type matching your requirement.

Comment: Will get it a try